# IIS Pool - Current numbers of failures

Tags: iis, application-pool

There is a setting In IIS for application pool ‘Maximum Failures’. How to check how many failures already happened?

Comment: There is no IIS administration API to query that number. Your best shot is to query Windows event log to see how many crashes were recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of "maximum failure"  indicate the maximum number of worker process crashes permitted before the application pool is shut down by Rapid fail protection. When the application crash reach the limit, IIS kill and shutdown the application pool, then you just receive 503 error Serivce Unavailable.

I think you can monitor it via Performance monitor->App_pool_WAS->Total worker process failure->select specificinstance object.

Answer (score 1):

IIS application errors are logged in as Windows Event on the server. You can use [EventLog.GetEventLogs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.geteventlogs?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to read them. However, you will have to filter through a lot of junk.

EDIT: Added Sample code:

```
var eventLogs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();

var applicationLogs = eventLogs.First(w => w.Log == "Application");

Console.WriteLine("Number of application log entries: " + applicationLogs.Entries.Count);

foreach (EventLogEntry entires in applicationLogs.Entries)
{
    if (entires.EntryType.ToString().Equals("Error"))
    {
        // An application error.
        Console.WriteLine("Source: " + entires.Source);
    }
}
```

Another way is to add [DataDog APM](https://www.datadoghq.com/product/apm/) or similar tool on your server. Then let DataDog alert you when the failure reaches/approaches a threshold.

Comment: How to distinguish failures?

Comment: It's not pretty. I will edit my answer with some code...

Comment: I am not sure that this filter will select only failures. If we just throw an error in our application the will be a log error, but it is not failure in terms of IIS

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Performance Counters to get a lot of stats about the machine. Im not sure specifically what "Maximum Failures" in IIS translates to in the performance counters  - but assuming that's fatal errors/app restarts there is a counter called `ASP.NET\Application Restarts` which is probably a good start.

(Enabling performance counters incurs a (small in my experience) performance hit - only turn on what you need etc. Microsoft recommend capturing a number of these counters on production workloads.

Checkout this [blog from Microsoft on performance counters in IIS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/performance-counters-for-monitoring-iis/ba-p/683389)